# How to downsample a signal in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am working with whale call files in .wav file format, the sample rate of the file is Fs = 8kHz. I want to downsample the signal ensuring that with the new sampling rate we can safely distinguish frequencies 0 till 100 Hz. I have tried to use the downsample() matlab function but I am unsure if this is correct. Thank you for your help!

```
[y,Fs] = audioread('FINS.wav');
n = 2;
Fs_down = Fs/2;
y_down = downsample(y,n);
```

Comment: not clear, down-sampling means you want less frequency resolution, where you want to actually have resolution between 0-100 Hz. what is your current frequency resolution ( rate divided by the block size)?

Comment: My current frequency resolution is 8000 / 100 = 80. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i dont think you understand what I meant. edit the question with a minimal example from matlab's sample audio files, for example: `[audio, Fs] = audioread('speech_dft_8kHz.wav');`, then truncate `audio` to the size of the signal you have (say N elements)... and go from there